# fsck keeps returning “fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]” on sd card for raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2, sd-card, fsck

My raspberry pi won't boot, I'm getting an "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,6)" error. I'm trying to solve it by running an fsck on the drive, as many people out there say this is the solution to the problem.

Whenever I try to run an fsck on the drive (the sd card is inserted into my mac), I keep getting a result "fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is what my terminal output looks like

```
Ciaran-MacBook-Pro:~ ciaranq$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            249.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.8 GB     disk1
1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    58.7 MB    disk1s1
2:                      Linux                         7.7 GB     disk1s2
Ciaran-MacBook-Pro:~ ciaranq$ fsck dev/disk1
fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]
Ciaran-MacBook-Pro:~ ciaranq$ fsck -fpy dev/disk1
fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]
Ciaran-MacBook-Pro:~ ciaranq$ sudo fsck -fpy dev/disk1
Password:
fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]
Ciaran-MacBook-Pro:~ ciaranq$ sudo fsck -fpy /dev/disk1
fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypq] [-l number]
```

Comment: Try splitting up your arguments - *sudo fsck -f -p -y /dev/disk1*.

Comment: Check the answers from this http://superuser.com/questions/503759/how-to-run-fsck-on-an-external-drive-with-os-x